# D3 Line Chart - can't get lines to show

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have been building d3 bar charts but am stuck on why my line chart will not load - throws Cannot read property 'length' of undefined d3 error so I think it's due to not pointing to the data correctly but not sure. The data I am using is:

```
   var data = [   
        {month: "May", emailsDelivered: 20000, emailsOpened: 10000, emailsClicked: 7900},   
        {month: "Jun", emailsDelivered: 28000, emailsOpened: 11000, emailsClicked: 5900},   
        {month: "Jul", emailsDelivered: 30000, emailsOpened: 15000, emailsClicked: 2900},  
        {month: "Aug", emailsDelivered: 40000, emailsOpened: 8000, emailsClicked: 6900},   
        {month: "Sep", emailsDelivered: 30000, emailsOpened: 10000, emailsClicked: 7900},   
        {month: "Oct", emailsDelivered: 25000, emailsOpened: 10000, emailsClicked: 4900},  
        {month: "Nov", emailsDelivered: 30000, emailsOpened: 9000, emailsClicked: 5900},   
        {month: "Dec", emailsDelivered: 36000, emailsOpened: 2000, emailsClicked: 2900},   
        {month: "Jan", emailsDelivered: 41000, emailsOpened: 5000, emailsClicked: 1900},  
        {month: "Feb", emailsDelivered: 46000, emailsOpened: 7000, emailsClicked: 8900},   
        {month: "Mar", emailsDelivered: 38000, emailsOpened: 16000, emailsClicked: 4900},   
        {month: "Apr", emailsDelivered: 24000, emailsOpened: 10000, emailsClicked: 7900} 
    ]
```

And here is the rest of my code. This is my first time posting on stackoverflow so I apologize if my formatting is bad.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.2);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")


var svg = d3.select("#emails_graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.emailsDelivered; })]);


var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d, i) { return (xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2); })
        .y(function(d){ return yScale(d); });

var lines = svg.selectAll("path.line")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("d", line(data.emailsDelivered))
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#888");
```

Comment: can you add the html code to the next snippet ?

Comment: this is mostly wrong usage of D3 API, I'm not expert in D3 but might worth to check the docs of `.data`, maybe it expects something different for line charts(likely an array of arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems going on.

First, here's a working jsfiddle of your code.
https://jsfiddle.net/28w8kk3u/

1. Your intent was that the variable `data` contains points for a single line, but when you call `.data(data)`, d3 sees an array with 12 separate objects. You need to call `.data([data])`. This way, d3 sees an array with single "object", where in that single object you have 12 data points.
2. The line generator created by `d3.svg.line()` needs to be told how to retrieve your intended x and y values from the passed in object. You tried to pass

`.x(function(d, i) { return (xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2); })`

as your x-accessor function. This doesn't make sense to d3 because you created an `ordinal` scale, which maps Strings to numbers (for ex. put 'Jan' into the xScale and it returns 40 ). The `xScale` expects your month names, hence

`.x(function(d) { return (xScale(d.month)); })`

Line generator:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return (xScale(d.month)); })
    .y(function(d){ return yScale(d.emailsDelivered); });
```

Then, to call the line generator, you need to pass in the entire object.

```
.attr("d", line)
```

The above is shorthand for

```
.attr("d",function(d){
    return line(d)
})
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much !!!!! Works great and helps me understand where I went sideways. Thanks again a million times over.